# Why does my libGDX TextureRegion.split code not work properly?

Tags: java, android, libgdx, scene2d

I am using scene2d in libGDX on Android as part of a game I am working on. I have a simple splash screen, which I am trying to display a single image on. The image comes from a file with two tiles in it, and I am using TextureRegion.split() to access it. My problem is, the entire image gets displayed instead of just the first tile.

Here are code snippets to illustrate what I am doing. You should be able to put this in a basic libGDX app to test it out. The image I am using is a png with dimensions of 460 width X 342, (2 tiles of 460X171). I am using the latest libGDX, as obtained from the libGDX setup tool.

What is wrong with my code?

```
TextureRegion[][] tiles = 
    new TextureRegion(
        new Texture( Gdx.files.internal( "foo.png" ) ) )
            .split( 460, 171 );

Stage stage;
Table table;

stage = new Stage();
table = new Table();

table.setFillParent(true);
stage.addActor(table);

Texture fooTex = tiles[ 0 ][ 0 ].getTexture();

Image fooImg = new Image( fooTex );
fooImg.setPosition(
    ( Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2 ) - ( fooImg.getWidth() / 2 ),
    ( Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2 ) - ( fooImg.getHeight() / 2 ) );

stage.addActor( fooImg );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TextureRegion#getTexture()` returns the *original* texture; i.e. the texture that it was split from. Use the actual `TextureRegion` (in your case, `tiles[0][0]`, not `tiles[0][0].getTexture()`). Your code should then become this:

```
TextureRegion fooTex = tiles[0][0];
Image fooImg = new Image(fooTex);
```

You can also use a static method to split your texture instead of creating a new texture region to do it for you:

```
TextureRegion[][] tiles = TextureRegion.split(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("foo.png")), 460, 171);
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked perfectly. Guess I should have looked closer at the API.